# Manipulate list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of equations:

```
eqns={a/b==c,d/e==f,...,x/y==z}
```

Now I want to muliply each of the equations with corresponding denominator, so that the result is:

```
eqns={a==c*b,d==f*e,...,x==z*y}
```

Is there a way to achieve that, or do I have to loop through the list?

Comment: `Manipulate` is a *Mathemaqtica* function unrelated to your task.  I recommend you change your title.

Answer (score 5):

```
MultiplySides[#,Denominator[First@#],Assumptions->Denominator[First@#]>0]&/@eqns

(*{a ==b c, d == e f, x == y z} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways is as follows.

```
eqns = {a/b == c, d/e == f, x/y == z}; Map[#[[1]]/#[[1, 2]] == #[[2]]/#[[1, 2]] &, eqns]
```

> `{a == b c, d == e f, x == y z}`

Answer (score 1):

```
eqns = {a/b == c, d/e == f, x/y == z};
eqns /. u_/v_ == w_ -> u == w*v

(*  {a == b c, d == e f, x == y z}  *)
```

Have fun!